# How to convert Jquery obiect with is returning JSON to C# soo I can show it in a MessageBox?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, winforms, awesomium

I was searching a lot, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Im using Jquery to send a GET request to a page, as a response Im getting JSON. 
 Im also using Awesomium browser.

```
var x = webControlMain.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("
$.get("https://somePage.com/someRequest", function (data) {
$(".result").html(data);
return (data);
});");
```

Now I want to show result in MessageBox, but i cant show a Jquery obiect in a MessageBox.

Server response looks like this.

```
{"success":"Some JSON value","target":130850}
```

How can i access to "success"and then show value in a MessageBox

Comment: you can use data.success to show success message. Like $(".result").html(data.success);

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question but Try creating a class representing the JSON, then using NewtonSoft.Json to convert the JSON to an object of this class. If the JSON is dynamic, try using dynamic as the type. 
First put this in another file:

```
public class OutClass
{

    public string Success{ get; set; }

    public int target { get; set; }


}
```

Then Use This:

```
string serverAnswer = "{\"success\":\"Some JSON value\",\"target\":130850}";

OutClass output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutClass>(serverAnswer);
//Then you can use output as if it were a normal object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below.
I have made only one change.
Use $(".result").html(data.success); instead of $(".result").html(data);

```
var x = webControlMain.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("
$.get("https://somePage.com/someRequest", function (data) {
$(".result").html(data.success);
return (data);
});");
```

Comment: did you at all noticed that OP is trying to use the returned JSON object in C# code. do you have `MessageBox` in JQuery?